# Mysql creating table issue

Tags: mysql

I started learning SQL but just in my first query, failed, i was doing exactly the same as the mentor explaining in the course but somehow his code worked mine not.
I also tried this query on PopSql it also did not work.
What is wrong here?[image]

Comment: the INT datatype has also len use: INT(11)

Comment: no INT(11) is deprecated use bigint

Comment: @nbk - The only difference is the range of the type. INT is a 32-bit long while BIGINT is 64-bit long, therefore it can store much larger numbers like 123456789123456789 (which cannot be stored as INT ). so the size (11) is only for display pre 0. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html

Comment: @BerndBuffen the numbers behind int are deprecated as int till bigint have fixed size and so the numbers are superfluous run the creete table with int(11) in mysql 8.0.28 and read the warnung

Comment: @nbk - thx, i didn't  know that, also there is no more zerofil flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the database you are running this query on.

To do this via MySQL Workbench:

Click on the 'Schemas' tab highlighted below:

[image]

Then double click on the name of the database you are trying to run the query on, the database name will be bolded once selected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell MySQL which database to use:

```
USE database_name;
```

before you create a table.

In case the database does not exist, you need to create it as:

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name;
```

followed by:

```
USE database_name;
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing. I recommend formatting your code using markdown. Please see the help for details (tldr: just add four spaces before each line of SQL)